# Doubts about creating a "more games"section with an UIWebView

Tags: ipad, url, uiwebview

I just made a humble more game sections for my game, when the user clicks the "more game button" i add an `UIWebView` that access to a web with links to other games in the app store.

It works well, after the more games web appears ons screen the user can access the links to each game in the app store. Also there is a close button.

1. But wouldn't be better to leave the app after clicking any of those apps? So they can continue to check the other games in Safari. Is this possible?
2. Or i should let my user access and check the other games pages on the store right from inside my app ?

I'm not sure about which one is the better approach, or how other games use to implement this feature, any orientation is greatly appreciated, i wouldn't like to have my app rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better user experience to send the user out to Safari. It doesn't make any sense letting the user browse your applications (or other applications) from within another app, which is not intended for it. To achieve this, all you need to call is:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourlink.com"]];
```

Comment: Yep, in ended with the same conslusion after checking more apps. It's definitely best. Thanks !